# Display Twig variable using JSON.stringify

Tags: json, twig, pretty-print

I have a function in a Silex application that executes a cURL statement and returns JSON string which is assigned to the variable `curl_result`.  This variable is then passed into a Twig template like this:

```
return $twig->render('http.html.twig', ['curl_result' => $result]);
```

In the Twig template, I am able to display the JSON string variable by using this:

```
{% if curl_result is defined %}
  <pre>{{ curl_result }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

which produces this result:

`{"ServiceAccount":[{"Type":"MATTER","ID":[{"body":"1980933400...`

Alternatively, when I use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`:

```
{% if curl_result is defined %}
    <pre>{{ curl_result|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

the only effect seems to be that it places the JSON string within double-quotes, and escapes the inside double-quotes:

```
"{\"ServiceAccount\":[{\"Type\":\"MATTER\",\"ID\":[{\"body\":\"1980933400...
```

Neither of these displays the JSON in a usable manner.  I want the JSON to be displayed in a human readable format and would like to use `JSON.stringify` for that purpose.    I am able to use the following javascript code and `JSON.stringify` some random text like this:

```
<script>
  var jsonString = '{"some":"json"}';
  var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString),null,2);
  output(jsonPretty);
</script>
```

If you're still with me after all that, here's my question:  How do I bring the Twig variable `curl_result` into javascript so that I can `JSON.stringify` it?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like this: `<pre>{{ curl_result|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>`

Comment: You are correct @Theo.  All I had to do was apply `json_decode` to my curl_result before passing it to `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your controller `$result` is a **string**, it contains a JSON string but at this point it is only a string. So when you pass it to `json_encode` it escapes all double quotes because it wants to encode a simple string.

If you want to use `json_encode` to pretty print this data, you first need to decode this string (exactly what you did in your alternative solution with `JSON.parse`), then encode it with pretty print option. So in your controller you should have this change:

```
return $twig->render('http.html.twig', ['curl_result' => json_decode($result)]);
```

You can then use `json_encode` to pretty print the `curl_result` in your twig file the exact way you tried in your second twig snippet:

```
{% if curl_result is defined %}
    <pre>{{ curl_result|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively, you can print `$result` as a JS variable in your twig template file like this:

```
<script>
      var jsonString = '{{ curl_result | raw }}';
      var jsonPretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(jsonString),null,2);
      console.log(jsonPretty);
</script>
```

Please note the use of `raw` filter when printing the json string.

Comment: When I use `json_decode($result)` I receive this error: `Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\mypath\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(467) : eval()'d code on line 68`

Comment: Did you change anything in your twig template? You still need to have `json_encode` in your twig file. You only need to change that line in your controller, but nothing else.

Comment: Oops, you are correct.  When I used `<pre>{{ curl_result }}</pre>` I only received back the word `Array`.  When I used the correct format `<pre>{{ curl_result|json_encode(constant('JSON_PRETTY_PRINT')) }}</pre>` it worked perfectly and I received back the human readable, pretty-printed JSON.  Thank you!